# Spring Security Basic Authentication only happens once

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, basic-authentication

Recently I am using Spring Security basic authentication for my REST services.

Below is the security xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <security:http pattern="/rest/**" create-session="never" use-expressions="true">
        <security:http-basic />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/auth/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <security:password-encoder hash="sha-256" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
</beans>
```

Spring framework and Spring Security that I use:

```
<springframework.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
<spring.security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
```

I map my REST services to URL prefixed with "rest/" and when I access the URL for the first time, the browser prompt the username and password field of basic authentication. I fill it with the right credential and my controller accessed successfully.

However if I try to access the same URL with browser again, it will not prompt me the username and password field of basic authentication again and directly access the URL.

I expect that browser always prompt me with basic authentication because I set create-session attribute to never.

So, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser caches credentials. Sometimes clearing the cache doesn't help. The only reliable way how to fake it is use Chrome's incognito window (Ctrl+N). But one prompt per one incognito window. So you need new incognito window when you want to enter them again.

This is the only way I found to test basic authentication manually.

Comment: I tried it using "never" and "stateless" and still, the incognito window only prompt once for both value. thanks man.

Answer (score -1):

From the javadoc for create-session. I think your application is creating a sessions and that session is being used.

> Attribute : create-session Controls the eagerness with which an HTTP
>   session is created by Spring Security classes. If not set, defaults
>   to "ifRequired". If "stateless" is used, this implies that the
>   application guarantees that it will not create a   session. This
>   differs from the use of "never" which mans that Spring Security will
>   not create a session, but   will make use of one if the application
>   does.
>
> Data Type : string Enumerated Values : 
>     - ifRequired
>     - always
>     - never
>     - stateless

You should try using

> "stateless"

instead of

> never