# Stateless session policy don't prevent browser from caching user credentials in subsequent request

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, browser, basic-authentication

I am setting Spring Security session management to stateless:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .httpBasic();
}
```

[image]

That is request header I got for second request. The browser stored credentials in cookie after first login attempt is authenticated and use it in authorization header in subsequent request. That would happen even when I restart the server. Only when I clear all cookies then the browser ask for credentails again.

One thing I notice is by setting session managment `ALWAYS` then a `JSESSIONID` is included in the first request response (`Set-cookie` response header) but for subsequent request that value is not included in browser request header.

If thats really the case, then what the real use case of setting session policy to stateless  in regards to **scurity** if those policies (stateless and always) dont make a difference (user need to be authenticated only for the first time).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Security Basic Authentication only happens once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25990452/spring-security-basic-authentication-only-happens-once)

Comment: See also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980247/spring-security-authentication-success-with-wrong-password

Comment: Not really they use stateless policy as i described above but it didnt give output i expect

Answer (score 0):

If you are sessionless and http basic then the basic auth authorisation header HAS to be sent with every request (and each request re-authenticated). Otherwise the request is not authorised and the user unknown. It is much more usual, in my experience, to use a token (rather than basic) if you are sessionless.

Comment: Thats not true i can still retrieve my username using 

```
  public String greeting(Authentication authentication) {
     
     String userName = authentication.getName();
     
        return " Welcome " + userName;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, because it’s coming in on the authorisation Basic header